# Differences in various Maltster's 2-Row

Tags: beer, malt, 2-row

How much flavor variation exists for 2-row malted barley from different malsters?  For example, how different is 2-row malt from Rahr, Briess, Canada Malting, Malteurop other than price?

Comment: Great question.  I am sure its largely subjective person to person.  I think the best bet to figuring it out is to do some small mashes and ferment 1 gallon batches of each one. Left as a comment because its not really an answer to your question.

Answer (score 1):

There is a large difference in flavor between maltsters in my experience.  Which you prefer is subjective and as pointed out, needs to be determined by experience.  My preference is Rahr, followed closely by Great Western.

Answer (score 0):

I've been listening to [Basic Brewing](http://www.basicbrewing.com/index.php?page=radio) a lot lately & a common theme I've picked up there is that small batch experimentation is the best way to answer these questions.

As the others have said, brew up a 1/2 or 1 gallon wort using each malt and ferment in the same location/temp using the same yeast for the same time & taste the result.  Bring friends too, taste is as subjective as olympic gymnastics so you'll need a panel.